# Can evidence ratios be calculated using information criteria other than AIC (or AICc)?

Tags: cross-validation, aic, likelihood-ratio, information-theory

I am familiar with the calculation of **likelihood/evidence ratios (ER)** using **Akaike's Information Criterion (AIC)** and its **corrected version (AICc)**:

ER = $\frac{1}{e^{-0.5*ΔAIC}}$

Is it possible to use a relative likelihood/evidence ratio for information criteria other than AIC?

I would like to compare the relative likelihood of one model against another, but with an information criterion derived from **leave-one-out cross validation (LOOIC)**, rather than **AIC**.  Can I just exchange **ΔLOOIC** for **ΔAIC** in the above equation?

If so, is there a citation to which I could reference this manipulation?

Comment: There's an interpretation of something like this for BIC.